# Detecting damage in League of Legends

Tags: arduino

i'm trying to detect when the champion you are playing in league of legends get's damaged. I'm trying to control the lights in my PC according to the events happening in game when you play league of legends. I'm trying to do something like the alienfx lighting for league of legends.

I'm planning to somehow get detect the events, sending a signal to an arduino in my PC case, which then control's the lights accordingly. Any idea how I can get this done?

Comment: What do you mean by detect events? What kind of data are you trying to catch? You have to be careful because as of Oct 1, most scraping of the client has been deemed illegal by Riot. So long as you aren't pulling any stats/data then you are fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place a man in the middle (aka proxy) between your client and the server to detect such events. I have recently done this between a Peer to Peer Star Ship Simulator. Where the Proxy detects the events and send commands to the Arduino's Serial Port.

You may also be able to create a plug in to your browser to what for such events.

Comment: So, it IS possible. Guess I need to search more on the internet to find out how it can be done. I'm an engineering student, not that familiar with the proxy, server kind of programming. Anyway thank you for your idea.